# cassandra centos 6.4 error

Tags: cassandra, centos, centos6

I am installing Cassandra . Server CentOS release 6.4.
I followed the datastax site http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installRHEL.html
     The service cassandra start without error but when I upload the command nodetool status

I had this error:

```
Error: The node does not have system_traces yet, probably still bootstrapping
```

And for cqlsh:

```
Connection error: {'127.0.0.1': error (111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)] Last error: Connection refused"
```

And here is the error in the log of cassandra:

```
ERROR [MemtableFlushWriter: 1] 2017-02-09 08: 21: 10,592 CassandraDaemon.java:205 - Exception in thread Thread [MemtableFlushWriter: 1,5, hand]
Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jna.Native
At org.apache.cassandra.utils.memory.MemoryUtil.allocate (MemoryUtil.java:97) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.util.Memory. <Init> (Memory.java:74) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SafeMemory. <Init> (SafeMemory.java:32) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata $ Writer. <Init> (CompressionMetadata.java:316) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressionMetadata $ Writer.open (CompressionMetadata.java:330) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.CompressedSequentialWriter. <Init> (CompressedSequentialWriter.java:76) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.util.SequentialWriter.open (SequentialWriter.java:163) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigTableWriter. <Init> (BigTableWriter.java:73) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.big.BigFormat $ WriterFactory.open (BigFormat.java:93) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.format.SSTableWriter.create (SSTableWriter.java:96) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.create (SimpleSSTableMultiWriter.java:114) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.AbstractCompactionStrategy.createSSTableMultiWriter (AbstractCompactionStrategy.java:519) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.CompactionStrategyManager.createSSTableMultiWriter (CompactionStrategyManager.java:497) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.createSSTableMultiWriter (ColumnFamilyStore.java:480) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.createFlushWriter (Memtable.java:439) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.writeSortedContents (Memtable.java:371) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.flush (Memtable.java:332) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore $ Flush.run (ColumnFamilyStore.java:1054) ~ [apache-cassandra-3.0.9.jar: 3.0.9]
At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker {ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~ [na: 1.8.0_121]
At java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor $ Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~ [na: 1.8.0_121]
At java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:745) ~ [na: 1.8.0_121]
```

Comment: have you installed jna? as in yum install jna?

Comment: Yes 
when i execute yum install jna 
`Package jna-3.2.4-2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do`

Answer (score 0):

Please check rpc_addres parameter on cassandra.yaml and try to change as your host ip.

Comment: it's not related to that error - it couldn't initialize the JNA library... Most probably the issue with exec permissions in the temp folder